# Failure while exporting table from Oracle XE Database

Tags: oracle, expdp, oracle-dump, ora-06512

We have XE running on a docker container. When trying to export a table I got the below error

```
expdp test/test@XE tables=UserProfile directory=/tmp dumpfile=profile.dmp logfile=logger

ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39213: Metadata processing is not available
```

I googled a bit and found that I need to execute the below command but that failed too

```
execute dbms_metadata_util.load_stylesheets
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-31609: error loading file "kucolumn.xsl" from file system directory
"/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/xml/xsl"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_UTIL", line 2397
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I traversed to the directory and found that the "xsl" directory was missing, is this directory created by default with XE installation or we require a specific setting to get the "xsl" folder?

XE was installed using the rpm - oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm. Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The value you specify as directory needs to be an Oracle database directory object, not the value of a directory on your file system.

```
create directory export_directory as '/tmp';

expdp test/test@XE tables=UserProfile directory=export_directory dumpfile=profile.dmp logfile=logger
```

Comment: created the directory in oracle, but the issue still remains the same. Something to do with the missing xsl directory. I am not sure if its due to the installation of Oracle XE was missing some steps..

Answer (score 0):

There is a 2011 discussion about this at https://community.oracle.com/thread/2278841. It says you have to copy the directory `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/xml/xsl`  from a working installation. So the problem seems to be a known one, and if you do not have a working installation you are out of luck.

The problem does not seem to be limited to Linux (I used the same rpm as the OP), as the discussion says the working installation can be “*even* a Linux one.”